# Date__range inclusive en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de hacer el siguiente filtro en una consulta de Django:

```
ben_filtro = Auditoria.objects.filter(fecha__range=[fechaInicial,fechaFinal])
```

Me arroja los resultados pero excluyendo unos que están en la fecha final. Los campos son de tipo `DateTimeField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que lo que te esté ocurriendo es que los registros del último día de `fechaFinal` no aparezcan, esto es debido a que si usas `DateTimeField`, interpresa automaticamente los días, y la hora la pone la hora la deja como 00:00:00.
En la documentación lo explica [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range)

Para que te incluya el día completo en la `fechaFinal`, una solución puede ser indicarle un 23:59:59 a la fecha, en algún caso lo he usado del siguiente modo:

```
fechaFinalMax = datetime.datetime.combine(fechaFinal, datetime.time.max)
```

Y luego en la consulta usaría esa variable `fechaFinalMax`

```
ben_filtro = Auditoria.objects.filter(fecha__range=[fechaInicial,fechaFinalMax])
```